# Recommendation of open source software that could build Heterostructure models visually?

Tags: software, software-recommendations, molecular-modeling, crystallography, heterostructures

I am looking for open-source software that could help me to build Heterostructure models visually, I've been working with BIOVIA Materials Studio before, but I got no valid license now, so I'd like to find some open-source alternative that works like BIOVIA Materials Studio. I tried the VESTA program, but it needs a lot of manual work to build a valid model for DFT calculation.
Any recommendation is welcome.

For example, in Materials studio, when creating a slab, I could set the parameter of HKL and thickness, then I could get the result, but in VESTA, I need to set some kind of transformation matrix and delete some atoms manually.

[image]

Comment: I think it depends a bit on what you mean. Maybe you can include some screenshots or images of what you're trying to build?

Comment: Maybe if you could give an idea what BIOVIA was able to do for you, we could supply some assistance.  ASE probably does this but not fully in GUI.

Comment: @TristanMaxson. I added some explanations about my thoughts.

Comment: Check out the LatticeMixer web-app https://www.latticemixer.com
Here is a video showing it's demonstration:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKRRmAPyX7w

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a fully GUI solution but if we can assume you get a primitive cell to work with, Atomic Simulation Environment can generate your surface.

For some extra spice, its common to want to make root surfaces such as $\sqrt{2}$x$\sqrt{2}$, so I included a final step which will do this assuming there is a valid $\sqrt{2}$x$\sqrt{2}$ to make.  There is also a `root_surface_analysis` function if you are working with an unknown cell.

```
from ase.build import surface, root_surface
from ase.io import read
from ase.visualize import view

filename = "primitive.POSCAR"
layers = 4
miller = (1, 0, 0)
root = 2

atoms = read(filename)
surf = surface(atoms, miller, layers)

view(surf)

root_surf = root_surface(surf, root)

view(root_surf)
```